# Creating formula using very long strings in R

Tags: r, formula

I'm in a situation where I have a vector full of column names for a really large data frame.

Let's assume: `x = c("Name", "address", "Gender", ......, "class" )` [approximatively 100 variables]

Now, I would like to create a formula which I'll eventually use to create a `HoeffdingTree`.
I'm creating formula using:

```
myformula <- as.formula(paste("class ~ ", paste(x, collapse= "+")))
```

This throws up the following error:

> Error in parse(text = x) : :1:360: unexpected 'else'
>   1:e+spread+prayforsonni+just+want+amp+argue+blxcknicotine+mood+now+right+actually+herapatra+must+simply+suck+there+always+cookies+ever+everything+getting+nice+nigga+they+times+abu+all+alliepickl

The `paste` part in the above statement works fine but passing it as an argument to `as.formula` is throwing all kinds of weird problems.

Comment: Do you have a column named "else"? It seems to throw an error: `as.formula(paste("class ~ ", paste(c("or","else"), collapse= "+")))`
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:13: unexpected 'else'
1: class ~  or+else

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you have R keywords as column names. `else` is a keyword so you can't use it as a regular name.

A simplified example:

```
s <- c("x", "else", "z")
f <- paste("y~", paste(s, collapse="+"))
formula(f)
# Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:10: unexpected '+'
# 1: y~ x+else+
#              ^
```

The solution is to wrap your words in backticks "`" so that R will treat them as non-syntactic variable names.

```
f <- paste("y~", paste(sprintf("`%s`", s), collapse="+"))
formula(f)
# y ~ x + `else` + z
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce your data-set first

```
dat_small <- dat[,c("class",x)]
```

and then use

```
myformula <- as.formula("class ~ .")
```

The `.` means using all other (all but class) column.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `reformulate`

```
 reformulate(setdiff(x, 'class'), response='class')
 #class ~ Name + address + Gender
```

where 'x' is

```
  x <- c("Name", "address", "Gender", 'class')
```

If R keywords are in the 'x', you can do

```
   reformulate('.', response='class')
   #class ~ .
```