# Going from a list of variable names to a valid formula call

Tags: r

I have dataset `df`

```
df<-data.frame(outcome=sample(c(0,1),100,T),
               v1=rnorm(100,10,2),
               v2=rnorm(100,10,2),
               v3=rnorm(100,10,2),
               v4=rnorm(100,10,2),
               v5=rnorm(100,10,2))
```

And I make a list of variables I want to look at in a later model:

```
list<-c("v1","v3","v5")
```

And I want to be able to manipulate `list` in order to enter it into a glm model:

```
magical steps
.
.
.
```

To give the desired formula call:

```
glm(outcome~v1+v3+v5,data=df,family="binomial")
```

Where `glm(outcome~` and `,data=df,family="binomial")` are preset, but `v1+v3+v5` is the result of manipulations on `list`.

When my `list` is only a length of 1, I can get away with `~ df[,list]`, but when `length(list) > 1` I get:

```
ERROR: R: invalid type (list) for variable 'df[, list]'
```

I've also tried creating a smaller dataset:

```
predictors<-df[,list]
```

and entering that in:

```
glm(outcome~predictors,data=df,family="binomial")
```

but I get a similar error:

```
ERROR: R: invalid type (list) for variable 'predictors'
```

Thank you!

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555473/creating-formula-using-very-long-strings-in-r

Comment: also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12967797/324364).